# MongoDB Aggregate data by document keys

Tags: mongodb

I have a document which holds aggregated data and the dates for each day are created by the keys (`Y2015-M04-D18`) forms the date:

**Data**

```
{
    'Y2015': {
        'M04': {
            'D18': 100,
            'D19': 200
        }
    },
    'order_id': 'VjprK',
    'user_id': '777'
}

{
    'Y2015': {
        'M04': {
            'D18': 100,
            'D19': 20
        }
    },
    'order_id': 'LaOPX',
    'user_id': '777'
}

{
    'Y2015': {
        'M04': {
            'D18': 100,
            'D19': 50
        }
    },
    'order_id': 'cYwxf',
    'user_id': '777'
}
```

How can I query it to return the sum of `300` for `user_id = 777` and the date is `2015-04-18` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to it really:

```js
db.junk.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "user_id": "777"  } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$user_id",
        "total": { "$sum": "$Y2015.M04.D18" }
    }}
])
```

It's not actually a "two key" aggregation like you think. But actually because your data is structured by date this way it's just a matter of mapping the path to the value, which will always be consistent. Just remove the `$match` for more than one "user".

The problem with this structure though would be aggregating "multiple dates" and you probably should revise this if that will be your intent at some point.

Comment: Looks good, testing it now. but what If i want to use a date range? say 2015-04-18 - 2015-04-19 ?

Comment: @Broshi As I say in the last paragraph, this is not a good structure for that. You could possibly do it with mapReduce, but it would be **better** to "faltten" or at least place "days" within an array if you need to do that where the aggregation framework is a better processor for this. But the aggregation framework cannot traverse nested objects like this, that's why you probably should change it.

Comment: So, in order to hold aggregated data in my collection, would you recommend this structure http://pastebin.com/hDvrCSMg as a better solution from what i've shown?

Comment: @Broshi No would not recommend that. But you can always [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) here and I would recommend that, as well as actually providing that sample data in your question just as what happened when people edited this question. Links, tend to disappear over time, so as a useful "knowledgebase" reference to others it is asked that all relevant information is included within your question on StackOverflow.

Comment: You are right, here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751675/mongodb-correct-schema-for-aggregated-data