# Query a deeply nested mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Assume I have a Mongo database with the data organized as follows (and that I have no control over the data structure itself)

```
    {
    "id": 1,
     "data": {
       "y": {
         "2015": {
           "m": {
             "6": {
               "d": {
                 "28": {
                   "location": {
                     "country": {
                       "United Kingdom": {
                         "t": 50
                       },
                       "Iceland": {
                         "t": 4
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
      }
    }
```

As we can see above, the `m` stands for month and so on. Let's say I want to print all countries from a particular month with `id` as something. So in this case, something like

```
    function(id,month):
            ...
            mongo code
            ...
    end      
    # output "United Kingdom","Iceland"
```

What's the best way of doing that? I'm using Mongoid on Ruby on Rails so using that would be alright as well though I'm quite curious how this in accomplished in Rails.

Comment: Don't model like that, it's really bad. This was basically asked just a few questions ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751675/mongodb-correct-schema-for-aggregated-data

Comment: That's what relational databases are for...

Comment: This model is bad, I know. However, that wasn't my question. Is Mongo capable of querying like I said or is it theoretically impossible?

Comment: @Ingo it is possible you have to use aggregation pipeline