# formatting pre-aggregated data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to prepare a pre-aggregated data set from a log file for later analysis

for example, I have a log file such as this

```
2016-01-01 11:13:06 -0900 alphabetical|a
2016-01-01 11:20:16 -0900 alphabetical|a
2016-01-01 11:21:52 -0900 alphabetical|b
```

The data (after data/time/timezone) is split on a pipe

```
entry|detail
```

I'm creating a data set that has a separate document for each `year-month` and `entry`

my data as a result looks like this : https://jsonblob.com/56a7d7d8e4b01190df4b8a55

```
{
    "action":"alphabetical",
    "date":"2016-0",
    "detail":{
        "a":{
            "daily":{
                "1":5,
                "2":4,
                "3":5
            },
            "monthly":14
        },
        "b":{
            "daily":{
                "1":5,
                "2":5,
                "3":2
            },
            "monthly":12
        },
        "c":{
            "daily":{
                "1":2,
                "2":2,
                "3":2
            },
            "monthly":6
        },
        "d":{
            "daily":{
                "3":1
            },
            "monthly":1
        }
    },
    "monthly":33,
    "daily":{
        "1":12,
        "2":11,
        "3":10
    },
    "dow":{
        "0":10,
        "5":12,
        "6":11
    }
}
```

by using

```js
var logHit = function(data, callback){
  var update = {};
  var inc = {};
  var detail = data.data.info[1];
  inc['detail.'+escape(detail)+'.daily.'+data.date.d] = 1;
  inc['detail.'+escape(detail)+'.monthly'] = 1;
  inc['monthly'] = 1;
  inc['daily.'+data.date.d] = 1;
  inc['dow.'+data.date.dow] = 1;
  update['$inc'] = inc;

  collection.update(
    {
      directory_id: data.directory_id,
      date: data.date.y+'-'+data.date.m,
      action: data.data.info[0],
    },
    update,
    {upsert: true},
    function(error, result){
      assert.equal(error, null);
      assert.equal(1, result.result.n);
      callback();
  });
}
```

while the data that I'm looking to store is included, working with it as a object series makes it harder to process when it is retrieved. I'm using d3.js and having to convert objects to arrays.

How do I store the data in arrays instead of objects like this https://jsonblob.com/56a7da76e4b01190df4b8a74

```
{
"action":"alphabetical",
"date":"2016-0",
"detail":[
    {
        "name":"a",
        "daily":[
            {
                "count":5
            },
            {
                "count":4
            },
            {
                "count":5
            }
        ],
        "monthly":14
    },
    {
        "name":"b",
        "daily":[
            {
                "count":5
            },
            {
                "count":5
            },
            {
                "count":2
            }
        ],
        "monthly":12
    },
    {
        "name":"c",
        "daily":[
            {
                "count":2
            },
            {
                "count":2
            },
            {
                "count":2
            }
        ],
        "monthly":6
    },
    {
        "name":"d",
        "daily":[
            {

            },
            {

            },
            {
                "count":1
            }
        ],
        "monthly":1
    }
],
"monthly":33,
"daily":{
    "1":12,
    "2":11,
    "3":10
},
"dow":{
    "0":10,
    "5":12,
    "6":11
}
```

}

where the objects become part of an array, and the key instead is put inside an array, similar this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30751981/197546

Comment: Are you updating the subdocuments or is it always a new doc?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I create a new document for every `YYYY-MM` + `Action` combination, the daily and monthly counts update that document

Comment: Right, just realized you're incrementing the values in the sub-documents (nested objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDB, array documents can be referenced by index, but not by value.  For instance, in your target data model you can change the name value of the first array element with the update argument:

```
{ $set: { "detail.0.name" : "me" }
```

Or even increment a deeply nested value like:

```
{ $inc: { "detail.0.daily.0.count" : 1 }
```

But in both cases knowing the index is necessary, which doesn't seem like that would work for your use case.

I would recommend referencing the [docs on Array Update operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update-array/) as well.

Comment: I thought having to get the index based on value would probably make this more difficult, than just converting on read. And for using with a graphing library I have to convert the de-aggregate the data anyway.

Comment: Ya, I would agree that it'd be better to just convert the data on retrieval.  Good luck @Daniel !